# Joomla Fabrik email plugin: email to (eval)

Tags: joomla

I have a Fabrik form that should be selecting an email address to mail to based off the selection the user makes on the frontend select box. The code I am using came directly from the Fabrik docs but does not seem to be working:

My form value and labels are as such:

```
general => General
booking => Booking
entertainment => Entertainment

<?php
$contact = $this->data['contact___reason_for_contact'];
    switch ($contact) {
    case 'general':
        $email = 'email1@mail.com, emailw@mail.com';
        break;
    case 'booking':
        $email = 'email3@mail.com, email4@mail.com';
        break;
    case 'catering':
        $email = 'email5@mail.com, email6@mail.com';
        break;
}
return $email;
?>
```

edit: link to [fabrik docs](http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/email-form-plugin/)

Comment: "but does not seem to be working" How so? What error are you coming to?

Comment: no error at all, it just says message has been submitted.